# Android Nougat - Network Security Configuration for Charles Proxy

Tags: 7.0-nougat

I recently update my device to Android Nougat and found that i'm not able to **all** content of the traffic on my charles proxy, and when I used marshmallow/Lollipop devices, I can still see what I want to see.

Based on this [Android Security Config](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config.html#CertificatePinning), We have the control of the certificates we want to trust for the application we own. ( we need to add this config file into manifest.)

How about other nougat applications (api>=24) ? How can I see other nougat applications' traffic content? is there a way to do so since we don't own the application, there is no way for us to trust certain self-signed cert.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to to look at the network traffic there is still the possibility on a rooted device to use XPosed and one of the Anti-SSL modules (e.g. [TrustMeAlready](https://github.com/ViRb3/TrustMeAlready)).

Unfortunately XPosed is currently only available for 32bit Android versions and most Nougat devices I have seen use Android 64bit.

Edit 2023-05: Nowadays you can use [LSPosed](https://github.com/LSPosed/LSPosed) instead. It works fine with Magisk in Zygisk mode.

Or if you want to investigate a regular app from AppStore you can modify and re-sign the app (e.g. via APKTool) - of course this only works for apps that don't have an integrity check.